# Resteasy GZIP being ignored when packaged as a jar

Tags: java, gzip, netty, resteasy, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm having issues with GZIP annotation in Resteasy where it works fine when I'm running from main function (in Eclipse), but when I package it with Maven Assembly plugin and run it with an embedded Netty it doesn't work, the returned content is not GZIP-ed and there are no exceptions. I think that this might be from the assembly plugin, but if some libraries/classes were not loaded correctly, I would expect to see some exceptions.
Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added header parameter "Accept-Encoding" and passed the value gzip from your rest client?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Comment: I think this should have been a comment

Comment: @MohamadGalala Of course I specified "Accept-Encoding" header, otherwise this wouldn't have worked in a standalone mode.